# Getting current working drive in Qt

Tags: qt

I want to get my current working DRIVE, not path. How do I do it?
If it was for path I would have done something like:

```
QString curPath = dir.currentPath();
```

Not sure how to get the current working drive.

Comment: Since a drive is the part of the *absolute* path, you could have gotten the absolute path and then tested to check if it starts with an `[A-Za-z]:` pattern - then the first letter is the drive. Otherwise it's a UNC or another drive-less path, but I'm not sure if they can be a current path, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [QStorageInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html) class provides information about a drive - to get one for a directory:

```
QStorageInfo info(dir);
qDebug() << "Name: " << info.name();
qDebug() << "Root path: " << info.rootPath();
```

Comment: This gives me "CCase" as result, i want it in form of, for example "C:" or "P:"

Comment: @Aashu10 I've added an example of how to get this. Please read the documentation for info on the data available.